# Dynamically changing NSButton NSImage color

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

I'm trying to have an NSButton with an NSImage, similar to Apple's "Preview" app markup buttons that change color when selected.

From looking at the bundle resources, it looks as if Apple uses a PDF image (e.g. TB_annotMarkupUnderlineTemplate.pdf) and programmatically changes color when selected VS. having an alternated image that is blue.

I can't do image masking with the PDF image because it has alpha value.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: It's always good to include code snippets of what you've tried so far so people know you've at least made an attempt. It's also much easier to find an error in your code than to create a solution from scratch. :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, you wanted to change the background color of image at runtime.

i.e., on some event you will be changing the background color of image. Also as you are aware a NSButton dont have a background as they are drawn directly by cocoa ( aqua ) style.

You need to put some image and hide the title of the button(if you dont want title to be shown).

Here is my [sample code](http://www.keepandshare.com/doc/6022049/nsbuttonbackground-45k?da=y) for the same.

I have used an IBAction on NSComboBox,

```
- (IBAction)comboSelect:(id)sender {

    if ([[sender stringValue] isEqualToString:@"Red" ]) {
        [self.button setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"imgRed"]];
    }
    else if ([[sender stringValue] isEqualToString:@"Green" ]) {
        [self.button setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"imgGreen"]];
    }
    else if ([[sender stringValue] isEqualToString:@"Blue" ]) {
        [self.button setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"imgBlue"]];
    }
}
```

Comment: The image is just one PDF image that can change color when selected. Similar to Apple's Preview app (the annotations menu)